# Retrieve text using Watir

Tags: rubygems, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I've an html div like

```
<div class="main-div font-color page-padding">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align:middle">
            <img src="resources/images/info.png" id="indicator" class="sd-img" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top:-3px;margin- left:-4px;">
            &nbsp; 
            <font color="#1F91D0"> <b>{{someMessage}}</b></font>
          </td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

I'm running Ruby-Watir Automation scripts. I'm not able to access element with text  `{{someMessage}}` in `<b></b>` or `<td></td>`. How do I retrieve text value `{{someMessage}}` above?

I tried doing:

```
def getElementById(elementId)
  if @browser.element(:id => elementId).exists?
    @element = @browser.element(:id => elementId)
  end
  @element
end
```

where `elementId = id` of `td`. But I couldn't assign `@element` value?

Any pointers or sample code for this would be helpful? Thanks.

referring to `<td>` with id and `<table>` by `id` and access the element but couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zeljko Filipin, thanks. I later tried this -

```
def getTableElementById(tableId, rowId, colId)      
  @table = @browser.table(:id => tableId)
  @element = @table.tr(:id => rowId).td(:id => colId)
  @element
end
```

It works!

Answer (score 2):

You said that you have tried accessing `td` element using it's `id` attribute, but in the HTML that you have provided the only element that has `id` attribute is `img`. If that is the case, you can use `id` attribute of `img` to access the text:

```
@browser.img(:id => "indicator").parent.text
```